# Eu quero exibir dados de uma tabela da chave estrangeira na minha tabela principal, como eu faço?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

No PHP como eu faço para ao invés do id da chave estrangeira, apareça o campo que possui os dados?

Eu tenho uma tabela sala que possui, coluna `id`, coluna `nome` e coluna `tipo`.

E também tenho a tabela de filmes, as salas dos filmes eu cadastrei em outra tabela e eu quero chamar o tipo da sala, mas quando eu coloco para exibir no php, ao invés do `tipo` está aparecendo o `id` da sala.

Abaixo o código das tabelas...

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `filmes` (

`id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

`banner` mediumblob NOT NULL,

`nome` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

`genero` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

`tempo` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

`classificacao` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

`sala_id` int(5) NOT NULL,

`sinopse` varchar(1090) NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY (`id`),

KEY  `sala_id_fk` (`sala_id`)

) 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sala` (

`id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

`nome` varchar(20) NOT NULL,

`tipo` varchar(20) NOT NULL,

 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

)
```

Comment: Qual SQL você está usando?

Comment: Estou usando o Mysqli

Answer (score 1):

Cara, basicamente assim, é só questão de relacionamento entre tabelas (*Joins*):

```
SELECT FILMES.ID  
     , FILMES.NOME  
     , SALA.NOME  
     , SALA.TIPO   
  FROM FILMES  
  LEFT JOIN SALA ON (FILMES.SALA_ID = SALA.ID)
```

Concatenando apenas o valor da coluna *Tipo*:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(SALA.TIPO) AS TIPO   
  FROM FILMES  
  LEFT JOIN SALA ON (FILMES.SALA_ID = SALA.ID)
```

Desse modo, você terá apenas o campo *Tipo* sem a necessidade de um *While*.

Comment: Nesse caso como eu chamaria apenas os dados que estão no campo TIPO da tabela sala usando o mysqli, sem ter q usar o while para isso?

Comment: Editei a resposta, veja se atende sua necessidade. Ainda não ficou muito claro pra mim o que vc precisa... :/